# Use login_required with vary_on_headers with generic view in Django

Tags: django, caching, decorator, django-generic-views, login-required

I'm have a generic view where I use the login_required decorator in the urls.py file, like this:

```
(r'^my-url/$', login_required(ListView.as_view())),
```

Now, I would like to use the vary_on_headers decorator for this url, but I can't get it working.

I've tried:

```
(r'^my-url/$', vary_on_headers(login_required(ListView.as_view()),'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'))
```

but I got the following error during my tests:

```
response = self.client.get('/my-url/', HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')
  File "/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 439, in get
    response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
  File "/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 241, in get
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 94, in process_response
    if response.status_code == 404:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

If I try:

```
(r'^my-url/$', login_required(vary_on_headers(MyProductsView.as_view(),'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'))),
```

but I get the following error now:

```
response = self.client.get('/my-url/', HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')
  File "/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 439, in get
    response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
  File "/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 241, in get
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 26, in process_response
    patch_vary_headers(response, ('Cookie',))
  File "/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 133, in patch_vary_headers
    if response.has_header('Vary'):
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'has_header'
```

Any ideas on what could be happening and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mixed up the view function that you are decorating with the header arguments for the [`vary_on_headers` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers).

Try the following:

```
(r'^my-url/$', vary_on_headers('X_REQUESTED_WITH')(login_required(ListView.as_view())),
```

Or, if you want to apply the decorators the other way around:

```
(r'^my-url/$', login_required(vary_on_headers('X_REQUESTED_WITH')(ListView.as_view())),
```

Comment: Just one comment, I found that the correct header to add here is only X_REQUESTED_WITH, since the cache middleware adds 'HTTP_' to it already

Answer (score 2):

If you have a custom view class (or base class), instead of decorating every call to `as_view()`, you can use `method_decorator` to decorate the `get` method of your view, or even `dispatch`:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(vary_on_headers('X-Requested-With'))
@method_decorator(login_required)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

You could also create a mixin that does that.